# Not found in pattern matching

Tags: scala

Why  can't I do a pattern matching:

```
class Gender extends Enumeration {
  val male, female, unknown = Value
}


object MyObj {
  def getGender(str: String) = str match {
    case "1" => Gender.male
    case "2" => Gender.female
    case _ => Gender.unknown
  }

}
```

error `not found: value Gender`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Gender.male` requires that `Gender` be a value. If `Gender` were from Java, then `male` could be static member of a class, or, an element of a java enumeration. On Scala, however, `XXX.yyy` will never be a value if `XXX` is a class.

Perhaps you should define `Gender` as an `object` instead of a `class`.

Comment: but I need it to be an Enumeration. what do I do?

Comment: Literally just replace the word "class" with "object".

Comment: I think you should just read the Scaladoc for Enumeration. http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Enumeration

Answer (score 3):

This question has nothing to do with pattern matching.

A trimmed down version of your snippet:

```
class Foo { 
    val bar = 1
}

Foo.bar
```

gives the error:

```
error: not found: value Foo
```

because `Foo` is a type, not a value.